# Fix problem in off-canvas menu module for Barrio Sub-theme

Tags: theming, navigation

I need help with changing a Barrio(v 8.x-4.22) sub-theme of Drupal 8 
 This is what I've done until now:

- I installed the Barrio sub-theme
- I installed the *Responsive and off-canvas menu* Drupal 8 module
- I followed https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/responsive-offcanvas-menu/

The menu appears at the bottom of the page[image: this is how it looks now]
I don't know where the issue is and how to fix it.
I tried to enable the twig debugging (from here-> https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) and think that the problem is in the off-canvas menu settings, but I am unsure how to change them.

Comment: Hi, please don't  repost the same question, edit the original [question instead](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290280/customization-of-sub-theme-with-left-hand-side-menu). Thanks.

Comment: @Hudri it looks like the OP has little choice but to repost, since the original question is closed.

Comment: @IfkaMitko I'm sorry your original question was (somewhat unfairly, IMHO) shut down. Have you looked at the menu markup using a DOM inspector (such as Developer Tools in Firefox, Chrome, or another browser?) It sounds to me as if this is a CSS issue rather than a Drupal issue per se (which may be the reason for the uncharitable downvotes!)

Comment: @hotwebmatter the original was closed for a particular reason, reposting it doesn’t make sense (by definition it will only be closed again for the same reason as the original). If there’s a Drupal-specific question with enough detail to be answered, it can be edited into the original post, and that can be reopened. Please don’t fall into the trap of thinking that voting in any direction is personal or charitable/uncharitable. Votes are to indicate quality of content, in context of what’s a great or less than great question for this site specifically, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks @Clive, that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @hotwebmatter. I've used the DOM inspector and found that the "off-canvas-wrapper" is loaded from some default files from Drupal, but I am unsure how to change them so this module to work properly. I have reposted the question because when I edited the original one they did not repost it and only give an option to post a new one. Also as far as I understood closed questions can not be answered. Thank you for trying to help me.